# It won't pass through the variable? FILES php

Tags: php, post, file

I'm trying to make an image upload work...

I have a lot more elements of the form but I figure this the only important part

```
<form name="register" method="post" action="profiles.php" onSubmit="return validateForm()">

        <td class="col1">Profile Picture</td>
         <td class="col2">
            <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
        </td>
```

This is passed onto profiles.php

profiles.php has all the variables of the form passed through....expect for that one. 
I get the error "Notice: Undefined index: file"

This is basically all file is used for in the script...

```
    $target = "files/";

    echo $_FILES['file']['name'];
    //$image = basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
    //echo $image;
    $name = str_replace(' ', '_', $image);
    $target .= strtolower($name . uniqid());

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target))
    {

    //echo $firstName, $lastName, $UserName, $email, $DOB, $join, $gender, $likes; 
//just a test to see if they were working.


addEntry($firstName, $lastName, $UserName, $Password, $email, $DOB, $join, $gender, $likes, $description, $newlike, $target);
    }
```

Comment: Could you post your <form> element please.

Comment: I have now just updated the details.

Comment: ) Bro if Worked then select the right ans tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding enctype="multipart/form-data" to your html form tag. Ie:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: Nice. I'm happy that worked for you, consider accepting the answer so others that come on this question can see what the accepted answer was.  Thanks my friend.

Answer (score 1):

You lack `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your `<form>`.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you have not defined the file upload element 'file' in your form.

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
```

Also make sure your form's `enctype` is `"multipart/form-data"`

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Answer (score -1):

Bro `enctype="multipart/form-data"`